# Language Localization support for Grails application

Tags: grails, internationalization

I'm developing a Grails application that supports both Arabic and English language. 
I have a language selection menu and two files for English and Arabic messages. 
For English it goes well but when I select Arabic the text appear as `????????`. A page encoding is UTF-8. I have also tried UTF-16 but in vain. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is arabic text from messages.properties?

Comment: Nopes. from messages_ar.properties

Answer (score 1):

dude~! for me grails has shown you `?????` text means that it actually worked the translation process ...but ...you need to check if have the font also installed in your computer and in the web browser that you are using to test now.

I hope it is good to visit some Arabic site and then back use that font to write the text and test.
[Please refer this documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.3/guide/i18n.html)
:

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8_general_ci" />
```

try this. I didn't try before.

Comment: <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type"  CONTENT="text/html; CHARSET=iso-8859-6"> try this

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with file encodings. I opened the file in sublime text and saved it with utf-8 encoding. It resolved my problem.